# Outline information in navigator view in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

In Eclipse SDK 3.6.0, I used to have the outline information (all methods and attributes) of a file (class), in the Navigator view. I don't know why, but I can't see that information anymore. I only have it in the Outline view. I've been trying to change this in Window->preferences, with no success. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's never been visible in the Navigator view, as that View only ever shows the resource tree.  You're probably thinking of the Package Explorer View, or the Project Explorer, or whatever explorerish view is associated with the language you're working with.

Comment: really? I am pretty sure I could see it before, maybe I have a new friend called Alzheimer... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Once I have catch the same issue for PHPEclipse and PDT, I have found that outline is not working any more for single files with message "Outline is not available".
The workaround is to create new project and import file to project via "File" -> "Import".